# How can I get a fast overview over an table structure in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Is there some command like "show columns from TABLENAME"? I only know that .dump command, but that's really dumb in this case. It puts out all the data, too.

I need something to just see the table structure.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You'll need to use a [PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#schema).

`PRAGMA table_info(TABLENAME);`

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a command to serve the same purpose as the "Show Columns from tablename" command that I can use when I'm working with mysql.  when working with sqlite instead, and this does the job nicely

Answer (score 10):

`select * from sqlite_master`

should work I think.

Answer (score 6):

in SQLite 3, do:

.schema TABLENAME

Answer (score 0):

Another way, you can use SQLite Manager Add-on for Firefox

https://addons.mozilla.org/vi/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/